# Does the AWS Client VPN service support two-way traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, routing, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I have successfully set up the [AWS Client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) service in my account.

In a single VPC I have created a subnet to host my EC2 instances (10.10.0.0/20) whilst the Client VPN is on a 10.25.0.0/20 subnet.

Routing to the internet is working and via an Authorization section I have enabled Ingress access.

Connections are flowing from my VPN client to my EC2 instance but not the other way around. My research shows that this is because Client VPN is using NAT to get to the EC2 instances instead of routing. And as such, there is no route to go back the other way.

Is this even possible? Can i connect to VPN clients from within my EC2 instances in the 10.10.0.0/20 subnet?

Thanks